# How to automatically merge consecutively branches after a common parent changed

Tags: git

Hello fellow stack overflow driven developers,

when trying to keep MR small, one approach is to create a branch for small features which always base on the previos small branch. so let's create branch A, commit some stuff, then create branch B, there commit some stuff, then branch C from here and commit there some other stuff. After some comments on your branch A merge request, you would like to update A, but also B and C because they all build upon that one.

So for example something like this

```
                     B4 --- o
                    /
              B3---
             /
        B2---
       / 
---B1---o---o---o
```

then might result into a scenario like that

```
                 B4---o---o
                /        /
              B3-----o--
             /      /
        B2--------o
       /         /
---B1---o---o---o
```

So the question would be, if there is a git command or some kind of automation which does that all at once.

Update: Currently what I would be Doing is iterate over the array of `[B1, B2, B3, B4]` and do something like

pseudo code

```
for (i=0;i<ar.length;i++) {
   if (ar[i-1]) {  
      git checkout ar[i] && git merge ar[i-1]
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there isn't. Git doesn't store parent/child relationship with branches. Also, since your picture is misleading, it's not like git keeps track of which commits are on which branch, even though you as a person can think of it that way. Instead, the branch names would be attached to the rightmost commit (the last one) on each branch, which makes it much harder to reason about how the branch points were at some point in the past and thus it's hard/impossible to deduce this relationship automatically.

Comment: well I even do not require it to store them. if there would be some command like `git merge-advanced B1 B2 B3 B4` it could just do that by iterating over the list and merge i-1 into i and so on.

Comment: You could make such a command, but there is nothing built in.

Comment: I am really bad at this in bash, if you would have some basic example how that might look I would gladly accept your answer, if there is really no native way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not built in, but you can use a Bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "exit 1" ERR

while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
    git checkout $2
    git merge $1
    shift
done
```

When called with your branches as params (e.g. `./git-merge-consecutive.sh B1 B2 B3 B4`), the script will perform the following sequence of git commands:

> git checkout B2
>   git merge B1
>   git checkout B3
>   git merge B2
>   git checkout B4
>   git merge B3

Note that due to `trap "exit 1" ERR`, the script will terminate if any command fails.